# text contours in C#

Tags: c#, opencv, tesseract

I am trying to extract the text area and recognize each boundary through tesseract.
However, Areas other than texts are also recognized as contours. how can i extract only text contours? F.Y.I I use visual studio 2012, c# and OpenCvSharp. thanks you.

```
    public Mat RegionOfInterest(Mat image)
    {
        List<Rect> boundRect = new List<Rect>();
        using (Mat img_gray = new Mat())
        using (Mat img_sobel = new Mat())
        using (Mat img_threshold = new Mat())
        {
            Cv2.CvtColor(image, img_gray, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY); //GrayScale
            Cv2.Sobel(img_gray, img_sobel, MatType.CV_8U, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, BorderTypes.Default); //Sobel Mask
            Cv2.Threshold(img_sobel, img_threshold, 0, 255, ThresholdTypes.Otsu | ThresholdTypes.Binary); //Binary
            using (Mat element = Cv2.GetStructuringElement(MorphShapes.Rect, new Size(20, 20))) //ROI
            {
                Cv2.MorphologyEx(img_threshold, img_threshold, MorphTypes.Close, element);
                Point[][] edgesArray = img_threshold.Clone().FindContoursAsArray(RetrievalModes.External, ContourApproximationModes.ApproxNone);
                foreach (Point[] edges in edgesArray)
                {
                    Point[] normalizedEdges = Cv2.ApproxPolyDP(edges, 17, true);
                    Rect appRect = Cv2.BoundingRect(normalizedEdges);
                    boundRect.Add(appRect);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < boundRect.Count(); i++)
        {
            Cv2.Rectangle(image, boundRect[i], new OpenCvSharp.Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
        }

        return image;
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //윤곽선 검출
    {
        Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        Mat img = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToMat(temp);
        Mat mat = ip.RegionOfInterest(img);
        Bitmap bitmap = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(mat);
        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNz0y.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6pgs.png)

Comment: To find only text-edges you need to find the text, i.e. run the OCR. As far as I can see your example only does edge detection, no OCR at all.

Comment: I knew I was perpectly wrong. but i don't know what to do. this is so tricky. anyway, thank you,

Comment: I imagine you could either do OCR on the entire image and see if you can get the position/size of the found text. Or do OCR on each found rectangle, and see if you find any text. I have never used tesseract, so I can't provide any detailed recommendations.

Comment: your comment matches the direction I was trying to do. Thanks for the advice.